# Redmine - populate a custom field consuming a web service

Tags: redmine, redmine-api

I'm new to Redmine and could not find answers for some customized solutions. I've already posted this question on Redmine's forum, still no answer.

In my job, we're trying to use Redmine for controlling a business process, so we need to do some integrations.
Is it possible to populate a field based on a webservice answer?
For example, I have two combobox STATE and CITY, how can I call a webservice to give me the list of cities based on user option for a STATE and fill the CITY combo?

Thank you,

Marcio

Comment: Redmine is open-source so you are free to write your own plugin to modify your SATE & CITY needs, or anything else.